# Using material design resources with AppCompat library

Tags: android, layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-appcompat

I am building my new app with pre-v21 SDK, which means I have to use AppCompat library to use Material design themes and controls. I have a problem with Material resource files.

As Google guidelines suggest, I should prefer the following typography in my app: https://www.google.ru/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-styles
For example, for titles I should prefer 20sp Roboto font.

These styles are already defined in `android-sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\values\styles_material.xml`:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Material.Title">
    <item name="textSize">@dimen/text_size_title_material</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@string/font_family_title_material</item>
    <item name="textColor">?attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

But when I use AppCompat library, I don't seem to have these style files (why?)

What am I supposed to do if I want to follow the guidelines? What if I just copy-paste these styles to my own app theme - would this be a correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should use `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title` instead of `TextAppearance.Material.Title`. That's it.